# socket.io client not receiving message

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

When no room is specified client receive the message but when specify a room I am unable to receive message on client.

server.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var port = PORT;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('new connection made');

  socket.on('subscribe', function (room) {
    socket.room = room;
    socket.join(socket.room, function () {
      console.log('joined:' + room); // outputs joined: 1
      socket.on('send-message', (data) => {
            io.to(data.room).emit('message-received', data.message);
            console.log("sent to room:" + data.room);  // outputs sent to room: 1

      });
    });
  });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

client.js

```
this.socket = io.connect('ws://IP:PORT');

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connection made"); // it output connection made in console
  this.socket.emit('subscribe', 1);
});
this.socket.on('message-received', (message: any) => {
   console.log(message);
});
```

on server.js I have tried several options below but still unable to emit 'message-received' on client side:

```
// io.emit('message-received', data);
// io.to(data.room).emit('message-received', {
  //   room: data.room,
  //   message: data.message
// });
// io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('message-received', {
//   room: data.room,
//   message: data.message
// });
//io.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('message-received', data.message);
```

using latest socket.io library with angular 4

Comment: Any solution on this??

Answer (score 0):

based on what i see on your clientside and serverSide code, I believe the problem is in the clientSide code...

On your server, inside the 'subscribe' event the server is also listening for 'send-message' event, which you're never emiting from the client side!!

Therefore, if you emit 'send-message' event with data(this should include message) as parameter, only then the server would emit 'message-received' event to the client..

HOPE THIS HELPS!